# R- Applying function with multiple inputs to all dataframe rows using "apply" function

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have written the following function where I want to calculate the angle between 2 vectors that I input

```
theta <- function(a,b) {
angle <- (180/pi)*acos( sum(a*b) / ( sqrt(sum(a * a)) * sqrt(sum(b * b)) ) )
return(angle)
}
```

I am trying to apply this function on 5 similar dataframes separately. For every dataframe, each row stores info on an observation, and 4 of the dataframe's columns represent the 4 coordinates of a 4D-vector that defines a property of each observation

For all rows, I want to find the angle between the vector a, extracted from the 4 columns, and vector b, another 4-D vector that I wish specify. Vector b is different for each dataframe.

I am using the "apply" method and calling the function I created earlier to calculate the angle between the 2 vectors, and store it in a new column called "angle"

```
df$angle <- apply(df[,c(7:10)],1, theta))
```

However, I am not sure how to use the apply method in a way where I can manually specify the vector that is angle b when calling my function, "theta". Which is why I have had to resort to pre-defining the value of vector b when the function is defined itself, like this:

```
theta <- function(a,b) {
b= c(1,2,3,4)
angle <- (180/pi)*acos( sum(a*b) / ( sqrt(sum(a * a)) * sqrt(sum(b * b)) ) )
return(angle)
}
```

The problem is, since I have 5 different dataframes where I have 5 different vector b's, I have to define the function each time with a new b before I apply it to a dataframe.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format seems to be:

```
df$angle <- apply(df[,c(7:10)],1, theta, b= c(1,2,3,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

The map functions from the packages `purrr::` allows this kind of feature

For example `map2()` uses 2 arguments and applies the function

```
list_df <- list(df1, df2)
list_b <- list(vecb_1, vecb_2)
list_angle <- map2(.x = list_df, .y = list_b, .f = theta)
```

Comment: when I tried it and passed in my arguments as listdf<- vectors from all rows of the dataframe, and list_b <- specific vector of interest.

But in stead of getting a List of values with elements equal to the number of rows, I am getting a list of 4 elements (probably because the arguments I am passing in are vectors with 4 elements)